# Trigger fires AFTER event handler

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, events, triggers

My `ToggleButton` uses a `Style` with a `Trigger` to apply a customized `Template`. The code is like:

```
<ToggleButton Checked="MyEvent">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OnTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

As you can see, the ToggleButton raises Checked event too, the handler of which shows a dialog box. Now the problem is that the above Trigger fires only AFTER the event handler has executed. Is there a way to prioritize the Trigger over event handler, so that the Template gets applied and the dialog box shows afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Routed event's are executed first before any property changed event is raised for property.

But you can achieved this by `invoking delegate asynchronously on dispatcher` so that your `template gets applied first` -

```
private void MyEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { MessageBox.Show("Test String"); });
}
```

**UPDATE -**

You can set `DispatcherPriority` to lower value (`DispatcherPriority.Input`) so that trigger gets fired first and sleep for fraction of second on UI thread (not good approach but no other way). This will work -

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { Thread.Sleep(500);
                                          chkResultBoost.IsChecked = true; }, 
                                             DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I ask it to run the IsChecked Trigger here, instead of MessageBox? I tried doing `chkResultBoost.IsChecked = true;`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Put this in `chkResultBoost.IsChecked = true;` delegate as well. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Updated with another approach.